# How to detect the full directory in Python?

Tags: python, windows

I want to detect the full directory ( Like... C:/path/to/file.py? ) in [python]. And I don't really know what module to use, or something. So, let's imagine this function exists:

```py
some.important.modules.checc()
```

**If the Python file is somewhere in C:/Users/Rix/Downloads/Path/to/file.py, it would return C:/Users/Rix/Downloads/Path/to/file.py, or if the file is in C:/Users/Rix/Downloads/Some/very/interesting/path/to/file.py then it would return C:/Users/Rix/Downloads/Some/very/interesting/path/to/file.py**.

So, what function could do like the `some.important.modules.checc()` function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer your question, this should works for you.

```
path = os.getcwd()
name = "tfc.qws"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

The `os.getcwd()` provides the path to your current working directory (CWD). So, when you `walk` your `path`, the `for` loop will essentially loop through your directory to locate for the filename, `name`, you specified.

If the filename matches, then it prints out your CWD, concatenated with your filename, using `os.path.join(root, name)`

**Clarification on Egemen İm's answer:**
I don't have enough reputation to make a "comment", the `"\n"` in Egemem İm answer means to have a new line printed before each of your path.

The `sys` module essentially provides a channel to modify the Python runtime environment; whereas `sys.path` does the following: [click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sys-path-in-python/).

Without the `"\n"`:
[image]

With the `"\n"`:
[image]

Comment: Will mark as an answer

Comment: I updated the content with images, hope that can further clarifies it. =)

Comment: also, please write that `os.getcwd()` from the `os` module does that, so that other people know.

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt what do you mean? Do you want me to add on my previous answer with ```os.getcwd()```? I removed the code as it only prints the path to the CWD.

Comment: I believe I answered your concern on @Egemen İm's answer previously, but not your question. I have modified my answer, hopefully it answers your question fully.

Comment: The current working directory is process-global state. As such, it is useless. Since no one has full control over it, no one can use it for anything meaningful. Plus, it distinctly **does not** mean *"the path of the currently executing source file"*. Even if the OP comes around to explaining what they are looking for, this proposed answer isn't a solution to any problem.